# How to have a div below another div, given that the position have to be absolute?

Tags: html, css

I'm a bit hopeless at this - I know there are many answers already but in order to keep my website *mostly* responsive, how do I stack these divs on each other without having to change the position aspect so it stays in the centre but one is on top of the other? The footer is unrelated to the main content.

Currently they are overlaying each other at the centre of the page, but I want to find a way where "container" div is above the "icon-div"

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    align: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.icon-div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    align: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-100%);
    align: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img alt="Robert Xu" width="380" title="Robert Xu" src="http://i.imgur.com/gTgVruY.jpg"><br />
  <h1>徐博</h1>
  <h4 style="margin-top:0px;">Robert Xu</h4>
  <p><span class="zh">中國 上海</span><span class="dot">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;·&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="en">Melbourne, Australia</span></p>
</div>
<div class="icon-div">
  <p class="en">
    <a class="icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a class="icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a class="icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </p>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <p class="footer-text">&#169; 2014-2016 Robert Xu. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can have a common parent div which is absolute in position and place the two divs inside the parent without marking as absolute.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it will look like when you have a common parent div which is `absolute` and place the two divs inside the parent without marking them as `absolute`.

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    align: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.icon-div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    align: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-100%);
    align: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img alt="Robert Xu" width="380" title="Robert Xu" src="#"><br />
  <h1>徐博</h1>
  <h4 style="margin-top:0px;">Robert Xu</h4>
  <p><span class="zh">中國 上海</span><span class="dot">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;·&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="en">Melbourne, Australia</span></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="en">
    <a class="icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a class="icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a class="icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <p class="footer-text">&#169; 2014-2016 Robert Xu. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using display:flex,instead of playing around with positions

Flex is responsive for layouts

check this snippet

```css
.maincontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="maincontainer">
  <div class="container">
    <img alt="Robert Xu" width="380" title="Robert Xu" src="http://i.imgur.com/gTgVruY.jpg">
    <br />
    <h1>徐博</h1>
    <h4 style="margin-top:0px;">Robert Xu</h4>
    <p><span class="zh">中國 上海</span><span class="dot">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;·&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="en">Melbourne, Australia</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-div">
    <p class="en">
      <a class="icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a class="icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a class="icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p class="footer-text">&#169; 2014-2016 Robert Xu. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps